# Chrome Extension - Inject Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inject

I am trying to inject javascript into my chrome extension, however, I can't seem to get it to work.

My manifest.json file:

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
"js": ["src/inject/inject.js"],
"all_frames": true
}]
```

my inject.js file:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

//my code to inject here.

}
}, 10);
});
```

Am I missing something? When I go to a website I expect to see it at the top of the page, but I don't see it at all. Thanks.

Comment: Is your background page responding to messages?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to check that, to be honest.

Comment: Do you have `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` in your background page?

Comment: My background page looks like this:
`chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse();
  });`

Comment: Does the content show when you just use the jQuery callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a need for message passing, I would recommend adding jQuery to your list of javascript files and using `$(document).ready(function() { });` to run your code after the page has loaded.